# chainlink oracle http get request not returning value - taken from example but still is not working

Tags: solidity, remix, oracles, chainlink, remix-tests

I have my own oracle code that suddenly stopped returning any output. So I double checked with the official Chainlink oracle example on remix and that is also not returning any value...

I have sent the contract LINK and the contract gets approved, but the callback never seems to output a value. Keep getting 0

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";

/**
 * Request testnet LINK and ETH here: https://faucets.chain.link/
 * Find information on LINK Token Contracts and get the latest ETH and LINK faucets here: https://docs.chain.link/docs/link-token-contracts/
 */

/**
 * THIS IS AN EXAMPLE CONTRACT WHICH USES HARDCODED VALUES FOR CLARITY.
 * PLEASE DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION.
 */
contract APIConsumer is ChainlinkClient {
using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;

uint256 public volume;

address private oracle;
bytes32 private jobId;
uint256 private fee;

/**
 * Network: Kovan
 * Oracle: 0xc57B33452b4F7BB189bB5AfaE9cc4aBa1f7a4FD8 (Chainlink Devrel   
 * Node)
 * Job ID: d5270d1c311941d0b08bead21fea7747
 * Fee: 0.1 LINK
 */
constructor() {
    setPublicChainlinkToken();
    oracle = 0xc57B33452b4F7BB189bB5AfaE9cc4aBa1f7a4FD8;
    jobId = "d5270d1c311941d0b08bead21fea7747";
    fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // (Varies by network and job)
}

/**
 * Create a Chainlink request to retrieve API response, find the target
 * data, then multiply by 1000000000000000000 (to remove decimal places from data).
 */
function requestVolumeData() public returns (bytes32 requestId) 
{
    Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
    
    // Set the URL to perform the GET request on
    request.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD");
    
    // Set the path to find the desired data in the API response, where the response format is:
    // {"RAW":
    //   {"ETH":
    //    {"USD":
    //     {
    //      "VOLUME24HOUR": xxx.xxx,
    //     }
    //    }
    //   }
    //  }
    request.add("path", "RAW.ETH.USD.VOLUME24HOUR");
    
    // Multiply the result by 1000000000000000000 to remove decimals
    int timesAmount = 10**18;
    request.addInt("times", timesAmount);
    
    // Sends the request
    return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
}

/**
 * Receive the response in the form of uint256
 */ 
function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _volume) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
{
    volume = _volume;
}

// function withdrawLink() external {} - Implement a withdraw function to avoid locking your LINK in the contract
}
```

I don't understand whats going on. Does it not work on weekends or something random?

Comment: Did you find the solution? because i am facing the same issue with sepolia testnet
i am following this docs but still it returns 0 after i call requestVolumeData() the volume is not updated.
https://docs.chain.link/any-api/get-request/examples/single-word-response

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle address and JobID may be inactive, try this:

```
oracle = 0xc57B33452b4F7BB189bB5AfaE9cc4aBa1f7a4FD8;
jobId = "83ba9ddc927946198fbd0bf1bd8a8c25";
```